# Deadlock with a thread-safe std::cout

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement a simple, thread-safe workaround for std::cout by using `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` of the Windows API for synchronization.
I think the example code is self-explaining, so here we go:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

namespace mynamespace {

class MyStream {
    public:
        MyStream(void) : m_lockOwner(0) {
            ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        }

        ~MyStream(void) {
            ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        }


        template <typename T>
        MyStream& operator<<(const T& x) {
            Lock();
            std::cout << x;

            return *this;
        }

        void Lock() {
            ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_lock);  // Try to get the lock, irrelevant which thread it is
            // One thread successfully received the lock and entered the critical section
            if(m_lockOwner == ::GetCurrentThreadId()) {
                // Decrease the lock count of a thread when it entered multiple times the critical section
                // e.g. mynamespace::stream << "critsec1" << "critsec2"; mynamespace::stream << mynamespace::endl;
                ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
            }
            // Store the thread ID of the thread that holds the lock at the moment
            m_lockOwner = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
        }

        void Unlock() {
           if(m_lockOwner == GetCurrentThreadId()) {
               // Release the lock only if the calling thread is the owner
               // Note: This should be the last decrease of the lock count

               // Also reset the ownership of the lock,
               // e.g. for the case that one thread is able to enter the critical section two times in a row
               // mynamespace::stream << "crit first" << mynamespace::endl;
               // mynamespace::stream << "crit second" << mynamespace::endl;
               m_lockOwner = 0;
               ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
           }
        }

        MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& (*endl)(MyStream&)) {
            return endl(*this);
        }

        DWORD            m_lockOwner;
        CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;
    };

    static MyStream& endl(MyStream& stream) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        stream.Unlock();
        return stream;
    }

    MyStream stream;

};

bool alive = true;

DWORD my_thread(LPVOID t) {
    while(alive) {
        mynamespace::stream << "OWN THREAD" << mynamespace::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void waitForThread(HANDLE th) {
    alive = false;

    // Wait for thread to finish
    (void)::WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE);

    ::CloseHandle(th);

    th = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    HANDLE th = ::CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(&my_thread),
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    mynamespace::stream << "test print 1" << "test print 2";
    mynamespace::stream << mynamespace::endl;
    mynamespace::stream << "test print 3";
    ::Sleep(10);
    mynamespace::stream << mynamespace::endl;
    ::Sleep(10);

    waitForThread(th);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In my first post I mentioned that I received a deadlock sometimes when exiting the program.

The problem here was that I haven't called `LeaveCriticalSection` as often as I enter the critical section by one thread.
Another problem was that I didn't exit the sub thread properly.

With egurs help and my small additions, this stream should be thread-safe now.

Greets

Comment: I imagine terrible things happen when `main` exits and tries to destroy the critical section object while the child thread has it locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enter the critical section **multiple times**, increasing its reference count, but when you call `endl` you **release it once** so the critical section is still locked.

Store a thread ID  in your class to know that this thread owns the lock.
Enter the critical section and compare the thread ID. Equal -> this is not the first lock so you need to call `LeaveCriticalSection` otherwise update the thread ID variable.

```
class MyStream {
...
     void Lock() {
         WaitForCriticalSection(&m_lock);
     }
     DWORD  m_EventOwner;
};
```

**Edit**

Changed the mechanism for my solution from the original answer.

Here's working code:

```
namespace mynamespace {

class MyStream {
    public:
        MyStream(void) {
            InitializeCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        }

        ~MyStream(void) {
            DeleteCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        }


        template <typename T>
        MyStream& operator<<(const T& x) {
            Lock();
            std::cout << x;

            return *this;
        }

        void Lock() {
            EnterCriticalSection(&m_lock);
            if (m_eventOwner == GetCurrentThreadId()) {
                LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
            }
        }

        void Unlock() {
            if (m_eventOwner != GetCurrentThreadId()) {
                //error!
            }
            LeaveCriticalSection(&m_lock);
        }

        MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& (*endl)(MyStream&)) {
            return endl(*this);
        }

        DWORD  m_eventOwner;
        CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;
    };

    static MyStream& endl(MyStream& stream) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        stream.Unlock();
        return stream;
    }

    MyStream stream;

};
```

Comment: Hi egur,

you're right, thanks! Read first, then ask...

As MSDN says `A thread must call LeaveCriticalSection once for each time that it entered the critical section.`

I changed my upper posting to the current working solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682552(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After a critical section object has been deleted, do not reference the object in any function that operates on critical sections (such as `EnterCriticalSection`, `TryEnterCriticalSection`, and `LeaveCriticalSection`) other than `InitializeCriticalSection` and `InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount`. If you attempt to do so, memory corruption and other unexpected errors can occur.
>
> If a critical section is deleted while it is still owned, the state of the threads waiting for ownership of the deleted critical section is undefined.

Immediately after releasing the critical section your main thread has a small window of time within which it can safely exit before the child thread wakes up and tries to lock the critical section. When your main thread executes the `Sleep(100)` it vastly increases the likelihood that the child will have the critical section locked when main exits.